# Restore Database in WAMP

Tags: mysql, database, wamp, wampserver, database-restore

I had few databases related to different projects in the WAMP. I don't know what happened, Today, when I go to PhpMyAdmin, I was just able to see the default databases and rest of my databases are not showing and even the php code related to those databases are throwing database not found errors. But when I go to "D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.30\data" the folders with my DB names are there. But not sure how to restore those DBs and I don't have any backup of the DB, Can any one help me how to restore them?

Comment: I replaced full wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24 But it's showing databases, not tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy these file to another location and reinstall the same WAMP version after installtation copy them back to original location.
Please note that your WAMP version should be same, because if the version will change then mysql version will also be change.

Comment: Hi Rohit, Thanks for your response. I'll give it a try. Shall I copy just the "data" folder or complete "mysql" folder?

Comment: only data folder.Please note that your WAMP version should be same, because if the version will change then mysql version will also be change.

Comment: Then please give a green tick ;-) Glad to help you.

Comment: I replaced full mysql5.5.24 But it's showing databases, not tables

Comment: Replaced means?? have you backed up your data folders?

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to utilise Window's "Restore previous versions" feature. Right click the `wamp` folder (usually in `C:\`, click *Restore previous versions* and select the most recent date you know it was working.

**Note:** This will also revert mysql data - so you'll lose any changes after the date you select, but I have used this in the past when I needed to get my whole wamp system back to a working state when something had broken it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `my.ini` file? Just find `datadir` it should refer to db folder (e.g `datadir=D:/Wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.1.30/data`) - goodluck :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the complete data folder from old wamp mysql folder to new mysql folder and then inside data folder change the name of the file mysql-bin.index to mysql-bin.index-corrupt. Then restart WAMP. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall Wamp Server that must be same **version**. After reinstall if wamp show red icon 1. go to wamp -> apache -> services ->test port 80.
if its available . then apache -> services -> install services.
2. mysql-> services -> install services.
after that restart wamp..
100% work

Answer (score 0):

Copy data folder and reinstall same version of WAMP.
Once installation is completed, go to data folder: inside replace only `ibdata1` file from existing folder.
After starting WAMP, check phpmyadmin: you'll get all database and tables with data.