# How to restore mysql database on freshly installed WAMP server?

Tags: mysql, database

I re-installed Windows 7 64 bit on my computer.

Before, re-install I forgot to take back-up of databases but luckily I had stored 'data' folder already on another drive. This folder contains:

```
-ib_logfile0
-ib_logfile1
-ibdata1
```

and sub folders named on each database. Let's take one subfolder 'etldb' which contains:

```
-.frm for each table
-.ibd for each table
-db.opt
```

When I re-installed windows I also changed the machine name suppose it is 'xyz-pc' now.

I installed the same version of wampserver 2.5 at the same location and replaced the data folder with the older one mentioned above.

The username and password for mysql are same.

I can see databases in mysql prompt as well as in phpmyadmin.

**Whenever I query a table: For example, select * from tblcustomers; I get error saying that etldb.tblcustomers does not exist.**

I tried different methods after reading at Google and no one works to restore my database.

Your help is requested to restore my data in database. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restore Database in WAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425379/restore-database-in-wamp)

Comment: Thanks for your response. No such issue found!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the access to the wampserver already installed without any type of reinstall.

Just find the folder where the old wampserver was installed (default: c:\wamp). There click in the wampserver.exe to start the wampserver tray icon. You will see that the icon doesn´t turn out to green. It remains red warning you that something is wrong.

What you need to do next is click on the icon and in the menu go to the option: Apache > Service > Install Service. A DOS prompt will popup asking for a ENTER. Press ENTER and it will install Apache service again.

Next step is similar: go to the menu, then: MySQL > Service > Install Service. This time no DOS prompt for you.

The icon will turn to orange.

Finally, just click on the Restart All Services option and voilá! You will bring your old wampserver to life without have to reinstall anything.

Simple like that. Hope it helps.

Comment: A big time life saver.. Thank you